# Unable to run application using root user on Openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I'd need to use a tomcat:latest image on Openshift origin. I'm aware that this image runs as root user, however I expected it to work by giving cluster-admin permissions to the developer user:

```
$ oadm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin developer
```

Unfortunately I still get a:

```
Jan 26, 2017 8:05:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [/usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml]
Jan 26, 2017 8:05:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Permissions incorrect, read permission is not allowed on the file.
Jan 26, 2017 8:05:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [/usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml]
Jan 26, 2017 8:05:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Permissions incorrect, read permission is not allowed on the file.
Jan 26, 2017 8:05:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
```

Is there any way I can get around this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are users in the OpenShift itself (like `developer` in your example) and users that are using for running containers. They're different.

The command that you've used is for the first type of users. And what you need is to configure Security Context Constraints (SCC) to allow to `developer` to run containers with any UIDs (here I'm talking about system users that exist in the host operating system).

You can find more [information about SCC and how to manage it](https://docs.openshift.org/1.2/admin_guide/manage_scc.html#how-do-i) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can use official tomcat images without elevating privileges by using Docker build strategy. You have to make all tomcat files owned by `root` group, as described in  [official docs](https://docs.okd.io/latest/creating_images/guidelines.html#openshift-specific-guidelines), *Support Arbitrary User IDs* section.

I have the following docker file with an official tomcat alpine image, where i remove all the default apps, recursively change ownership of tomcat directory and then copy my artifact in webapps

```
FROM tomcat:jre8-alpine
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/* && \
    chgrp -R 0 /usr/local/tomcat/ && \
    chmod -R g=u /usr/local/tomcat/
ADD ROOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

Just make sure your app is not writing logs to `/var/log` or somewhere outside default tomcat folder, or adjust ownership of those folders in similar manner.